# gnome-terminal scrollback disappearing

Tags: 12.04, gnome-terminal

When I enter a newline in the commandline, or a command emits a newline, it makes a line of text at the top disappear, almost as though I had a 30 line scrollback. However, I have an unlimited scrollback. [image: running one command] [image: running the second command, some text disappears]

Restarting gnome-terminal does not fix the problem.

Versions:
Gnome Terminal 3.4.1.1
Ubuntu Precise Pangolin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about loading it to defaults . I mean

sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-terminal